# Angular: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Tags: javascript, angular

I try execute on my cards.component.ts

```
    notices: notice[];

    ngOnInit() {
      this.dataService.getCards().subscribe( data => { this.notices = data });
      this.notices.forEach(n => {
        console.log('test')
      });
    }
```

I only want show something in console for every item is on "notices" but show me this error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties
> of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Comment: first of all check that are you getting the data in `this.notices` before appluing `forEach`

Comment: Hey Mestre. I would recommend reading about observables.It is asynchronous in nature so most probably your notices is getting assigned after your forEach loop.To check this before forEach loop , log the value of notices.It will be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your subscribe is getting called after your call to `forEach`
The best fix would be to initialize your notices to an empty array and then loop through `this.notices` **inside** the subscribe call:

```
notices: notice[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getCards().subscribe( data => { 
  this.notices = data 
  this.notices.forEach(n => {
     console.log('test')
  });
 });     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array notices should be initialized in field declaration or in constructor of component

`notices: notice[] = [];`

or

`constructor() { this.notices = [] }`